# Why does Apache POI XSSF fail to write to servlet response outputStream?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

I've created a servlet which creates an XSSFWorkbook and writes it to the response's outputStream. Strangely enough, when I try to test the functionality in the browser (Chrome v54.0.2840.98) I'm only able to get the xlsx file once (the file opens up without any formatting issues and has the expected content as well) but if I navigate away from the page where this feature is available with the 'back' button in the browser and go immediately back to same page and try to get the same file again I'm not getting anything in the response. Additionally, my other servlets stop working too until I open a new tab. I've given it a shot in a different browser (Safari v9.1.2 (11601.7.7)) and everything is working as expected, no issues whatsoever. 
Here's the code that I use:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    Workbook workbook = createWorkbook(); //creates an XSSFWorkbook

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader(
        "Content-Disposition",
        "attachment; filename=\"excel-export-" + now.toString("yyyy-MMM-dd") + ".xlsx\""
    );

    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    workbook.write(bufferedOutputStream);
}
```

When I'm running the code in the development env I don't get any exception, the status is 200 but still nothing gets downloaded. Ocassionally I get a

```
   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException:Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/core.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller
```

Which, after extensive debugging, I can reproduce by passing a *null* to the workbook.write() function:

```
workbook.write(null);
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you for reading!

Javax Servlet API v2.5
Apache-POI v3.15
Java 8 JDK(1.8.0_111)

**UPDATE**
If I get an exception it looks like this(stacktrace):
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/darkstar85/b151e53b64498e1fb476d0f6f8ea4eaf/raw/ffb078c54b850922fcd4e467a6ebf9695aeb7354/gistfile1.txt

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: yes I have (i use IntelliJ IDEA though). Like I said, there is no exception in the debug console after the execution passes the `workbook.write(bufferedOutputStream);` line. The client gets a status 200 but the download never starts. The only thing that happens is that the favicon flickers for a fraction of a moment and that's it. If I try my other servlets they all do the same. The only thing that solves the problem is opening a new browser tab... It seems as if the outputStream gets inaccessible after the first successful download attempt.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: see updated post for stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the code of Apache POI, this can only happen if `StreamHelper.saveXmlInStream(xmlDoc, out)` returns `false`. Additionally this only returns false if XML-Transformation fails at the line `trans.transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);`.

However it just does a identity-transformation (i.e. a simple copy) here, so this can only fail, if the XML Parser that is available in your application somehow does not work correctly.

Therefore I would check which JDK you are using and if there are any additional XML Parsers added in your application, e.g. Xerces or any other and see if you can remove them.

Comment: thanks for the tip! After more debugging it turned out that one of our proxy components caused the problem. HSSF Workbooks made it through but not the XSSFWorkbook.